# Application of Double Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification, multiple-integral

> Find the volume of the solid bounded above by $z=4-y^2-\frac{1}{4}x^2$ and below by the disk $(y-1)^2+x^2 \le 1$ , $z\ge0$.

I first converted the equation $z=4-y^2-\frac{1}{4}x^2$ into polar equation, which then became $z=4-r^2\sin^2\theta-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}$. Then I also converted the equation of the disk which then became $r=2\sin\theta$. To get the volume of the solid I evaluated the double integral
$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0} \left(4-r^2\sin^2\theta-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}\right) rdrd\theta.$$
The answer I got in the end was $\frac{63\pi}{16}-\frac{16}{3}$. Is my answer correct? If it is not, can someone point out what part/s I was/were wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your expression.

Comment: There was a mistake in your working and so you got a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y=1+r \sin \theta$, you get $z = 4-(1+ r \sin \theta)^2- \frac 14 r^2 \cos^2 \theta$. In these coordinates,
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r(4-(1+ r \sin \theta)^2- \frac 14 r^2 \cos^2 \theta)  dr d\theta =\frac{43 \pi}{16}.
$$

Comment: I think your formula for $z$ might be wrong

Comment: You are correct, i'll edit

Comment: @PierreCarre so r must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1. Why should $\theta$ be from 0 to $\pi$ ?

Comment: @BBS It should not be from 0 to $\pi$... That way we would be excluding half the disk.

Comment: @BBS: You have your coordinate system origin set at $(0,0)$. He measures $r$ not from that point, but from $(0,1)$. Then to get a full circle, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: @PierreCarre why did you replace $y$ with $1+r\sin\theta$ isn't $y=r\sin\theta$?

Comment: @BBS It normally leads to simpler calculations if you describe the circle in a coordinate system with origin in the center of the circle. In fact, if you go over your deduction to the equation of the circle in your case, you'll see that it is even more complicated than the result you obtained.

Comment: @PierreCarre $y=1=r\sin\theta$ does not correspond to a circle. I am really confused with $1+r\sin\theta$. That is only part I was lost in your solution. Could you kindly explain where did you got it? Thank you.

Comment: $x = a + r \cos \theta$, $y = b + r \sin \theta$ corresponds to a circumference with radius $r$, centered at $(a,b)$. You check this directly because $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = (a+r\cos \theta -a)^2 + (b+r \sin \theta -b )^2 = r^2\cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta = r^2.$$

You can think of this as shifting a circumference centered at $(0,0)$:

$$(x,y) = (a,b) + r (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your last integration. Your formula is right, but you got the wong answer
$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0} \left(4-r^2\sin^2\theta-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}\right) rdrd\theta=
\\
=\int_0^\pi\left(\frac424\sin^2\theta-\frac14(2\sin\theta)^4\sin^2\theta-\frac14(2\sin\theta)^4\frac 14\cos^2\theta)\right)d\theta\\=\int_0^\pi(8\sin^2\theta-\frac1{4}16\sin^6\theta-\frac1{16}16\sin^4\theta\cos^2\theta)d\theta\\=\frac{43\pi}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your method. It is definitely more tedious as the upper bound of the first integral will be $2 \sin \theta$. Also, you are taking the angle from the origin for a disk with center at $(0,1)$ and radius $1$, and hence $0$ to $\pi$ will be the bound for the whole disk area.

$ \displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0} \left(4-r^2\sin^2\theta-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}\right) rdrd\theta = \displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}[2r^2-\frac{r^4}{4} \sin^2\theta - \frac{r^4}{16} \cos^2\theta]_0^{2\sin\theta} \, d\theta$

$\displaystyle \, = \int_0^{\pi} (8\sin^2 \theta - \sin^4 \theta \cos^2 \theta - 4 \sin^6 \theta) d \theta = \frac{43 \pi}{16}$

May be you missed to multiply by $r$ before first integration ($r dr$) and hence got a wrong answer.

Comment: Now I know. I had an incorrect exponent for the term $4\sin^6\theta$. I wrote $4\sin^3\theta$. Nevertheless, I got $8\sin^2\theta$ and $-\sin^4\theta\cos^2\theta$ correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.